# How to run oracle table with subpartition from shell

Tags: oracle, shell

I have a table in oracle with contains a lot of partitions i have to call the subpartitions  from shell.This is my query..

```
SELECT 1,
   'Same MSISDN with different connection type in TABS and HLR',
   count(*)
 FROM profile_master_wk_kwt_hlrd subpartition ($mwk)
 WHERE Billing_MSISDN <> '***'
 AND hlr_msisdn <>'***'
 AND Billing_Served_Type <> HLR_Served_Type ;
 COMMIT;
```

when i am running this query without subpartition ($mwk) this is running fine.But when i include that portion this is not working.Please anyone help

Comment: "... this is not working" how?

Comment: when i write the query in oracle(i am using toad) without subpartition ($mwk) its running but when i include that toad is showing ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: Print out the actual SQL being generated prior to running it. Check the syntax of the generated SQL and you'll probably find the error.

Comment: what is meant by actual SQl

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have your subpartiton name starting with a special character. Try changing the subpartition name to start with a character.

If you are keeping the same name try including the name within double quote. But i am not sure if adding double quote would work.

Comment: but it shows SQl command not properly ended that means should i have to include something after the subpartition name??

Comment: No its not needed you just have to specify "select * from table_name subpartition (name)"